# Parallel queries - SELECT and UPDATE - too fast select or too slow update problem

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, transactions

I started one script in a few threads, which takes some data from database

```
SELECT * from `base` LIMIT 1 where `used` = 0
```

and then update this row

```
UPDATE `base` set `used` = 1 where id ...
```

The problem is: parallel threads often take same record from table. UPDATE can not get in time to avoid this.

What should I do?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Learn about table locking in your database.

Comment: With Postgres I would say you should use `select ... for update skip locked` but the use of the dreaded, non-standard backticks suggests you are using MySQL

Comment: Worst case, use a transaction, better rework into a single statement so you use one implicitly or rework you process so it is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,  Gordon Linoff ! 
I should use LOCK TABLE `table` WRITE and then UNLOCK TABLES;